# Changing a Variable Set to a Value in a Dictionary Changes the Dictionaries Value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary with integers as keys, the values are all integers inside a list. I set a variable to be equal to one of the values but if I subtract one from an integer in the list in the variable, it also subtracts one from the integer in the list in the value in the dictionary.

```
mydictionary = {1: [10]}
variable0 = mydictionary[1]
variable0[0] -= 1
print(mydictionary)
```

This prints out

```
{1: [9]}
```

when it should be printing out

```
{1: [10]}
```

as I never changed the value inside the dictionary, only the variable.

Why does this happen and is there a way to make it print out {1: [10]} while also changing the variable?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong, read this https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You *are* mutating the list *within* the dictionary, assignment never copies data

Comment: You're updating the value of the item in the list via a list subscription. Hard to tell why you would expect this to behave differently. See [Assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt).

Comment: You should instead assign the value in the list to a new variable and then update: `variable0 = mydictionary[1][0]; variable0 -= 1`

Answer (score 0):

Though you changed the value of the JSON object, you have not overwritten the value in JSON.

```
mydictionary = {1: [10]}
variable0 = mydictionary[1]
variable0[0] -= 1
mydictionary[1] = [variable0[0]] # here you are overwriting the value
print(mydictionary)
```

Now the output will be `{1: [9]}`

Cheers!

Comment: There's no JSON object here. And I don't see how your answer solves their problem.

Comment: mydictionary[1] = [variable0[0]]; this line solves the problem. And i referred Python dict as JSON Object. Thanks for notifying the error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the list inside the dictionary is one value and both the dictionary and the variable refer to that value. The dictionary and variable are only ways for the program to refer to that value. You have to go through the dictionary or variable to change the value and once changed, both the dictionary and the variable still refer to that value.

I change the value by subtracting one from it by going through the variable.
I then access the same value when I go through the dictionary.

This means that the dictionary is accessing the value that was changed by the variable. There is only one value throughout this program.

---

I can also change the code to

```
mydictionary = {1: [10]}
variable0 = mydictionary[1].copy()
variable0[0] -= 1
print(mydictionary)
```

This sets variable0 to a new value that is the same as the value in the dictionary. These are two different values that equal the same thing, changing one won't change the other unlike before.